# Copy file with smbclient and path to directory

Tags: command-line, samba, copy

I'm stuck in `NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME` error but can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

My objective: copy a file from ubuntu to windows in a simple command line to be called by php.

The problem: when I add more than one folder to the path it throws the `NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME` error.

Example:

```
smbclient -U someuser%somepassword //10.0.1.250/Home/Public/Offline -c 'put "test.deb"'

Domain=[FILESERVER] OS=[Windows Server 2012 Standard 9200] Server=[Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

But when I try just:

```
smbclient -U someuser%somepassword //10.0.1.250/Home
```

It connects and I can do a put with the same file:

```
smb: \> cd Public/Offline
smb: \Public\Offline\> put test.deb
```

So it not seems to be a permissions issue.

What could I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use the [*initial directory*](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=smbclient&manpath=CentOS+7.1) option (`--directory Public/Offline`)

Comment: ``smbclient -U someuser%somepassword //10.0.1.250/Home  --directory Public/Offline -c 'put "test.deb"'`` is working. Thanks!

Comment: i am gertting this error 
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME

Comment: @JayMomaya check this https://serverfault.com/a/137298 it said this is caused by insufficient right to the whole path so check permissions to all dirs along the path you use

Comment: Make sure if you are using server_name instead of server_ip - you are using the full qualified name. like xx.yy.com or xx.yy.net etc.